# How to plot error bars with lines in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have two data files

```
# a.txt
1,    1,   1
2,    4,   1
3,    9,   5
4,   16,   1
5,   25,  1
6,   36,  1
7,   49,  1
8,   64,  1
9,   81,  1
10, 100,  1
```

and

```
# b.txt
1,    1,   1
2,    3,   1
3,   10,   1
4,   17,   1
5,   24,  1
6,   34,  1
7,   48,  1
8,   62,  1
9,   85,  3
10, 98,  1
```

I want to plot these two data in a single image with its error bars and top right label as "a" and "b", Initially I tried to plot the files using

```
plot 'a.txt' u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars l, 'b.txt' u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars l
```

which plotted the error graph but not the lines, then I tried this method

```
plot 'a.txt' u 1:2 with lines,'a.txt' u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars,'b.txt' u 1:2 with lines,'b.txt' u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars
```

Now it plots the error bars and the lines but now I have four labels instead of two.

How can I plot error bars with lines in gnuplot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument is named `errorlines`

```
$a <<EOD
1,    1,   1
2,    4,   1
3,    9,   5
4,   16,   1
5,   25,  1
6,   36,  1
7,   49,  1
8,   64,  1
9,   81,  1
10, 100,  1
EOD
$b <<EOD
1,    1,   1
2,    3,   1
3,   10,   1
4,   17,   1
5,   24,  1
6,   34,  1
7,   48,  1
8,   62,  1
9,   85,  3
10, 98,  1
EOD

plot $a u 1:2:3 w errorlines, $b u 1:2:3 w errorlines l
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help , if possible can you tell me how did you import data to the variable $a,$b

Comment: This is called datablock. You get more information with `help datablock` or on page 39 in http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.2/Gnuplot_5.2.pdf.